# Sender ID Cordova Plugin Push

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que precisa estar apto a receber notificações via servidor, e para isso, optei na utilização de um plugin chamado phonegap-plugin-push

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
  "android": {
      "senderID": "XXXXXXXX"
  },
  "ios": {
    "sound": true,
    "alert": true,
    "badge": true
  },
  "windows": {}
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
  alert("registration event: " + data.registrationId);
  var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
  if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
      // Save new registration ID
      localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
      // Post registrationId to your app server as the value has changed
  }
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("push error = " + e.message);
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
 console.log('notification event');
 navigator.notification.alert(
    data.message,         // message
    null,                 // callback
    data.title,           // title
    'Ok'                  // buttonName
 );
});
```

Onde, independentemente do Sender ID utilizado, ele retorna o mesmo Device ID, já criei outros projetos no google firebase, para alterar o senderID e consequentemente alterar o device ID, porém sempre retorna o mesmo.

Desde já, agradeço pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, estava utilizando a versão 2.1.2, por algum motivo não estava funcionando corretamente com o Android, então tive que fazer um downgrade para a versão 1.8.0, assim, funcionou perfeitamente.